# What are "Innermost" and "Outermost" indices in a dataset?

Tags: dataframe, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand how to constuct datasets for tensorflow, but I'm confused by this tutorial's description:

```
All shapes are: (batch, time, features)
Window shape: (3, 7, 19)
Inputs shape: (3, 6, 19)
Labels shape: (3, 1, 1)
```

> Typically, data in TensorFlow is packed into arrays where the
> outermost index is across examples (the "batch" dimension). The middle
> indices are the "time" or "space" (width, height) dimension(s). The
> innermost indices are the features.
>
> The code above took a batch of three 7-time step windows with 19
> features at each time step. It splits them into a batch of 6-time step
> 19-feature inputs, and a 1-time step 1-feature label.

Source: [Time series forecasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series)

I am confused by many of the terms here, which is making it difficult to understand what is being said:

- What is "innermost" and "outermost"? My intuition tells me that index 0 is the innermost, but that contradicts them describing the batch index as "outermost". What is "outer" about index 0?
- What are the "middle indices"? Since the phrase is a plural, I would assume there are 2 middle indices, implying 4 dimensions in total, but there are only 3.
- The middle indices are described as representing "time or space". What is meant by that in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working with these datasets for a while now and I think I can have a go at answering this myself:

**Innermost vs outermost:**

I think the intuition behind *innermost* and *outermost* lies in where you would put the indexing brackets. Take this 2D array:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

This array has 3 items in the *outermost* dimension because you access those with the first bracket/parenthesis (it is not *inside* the other dimensions). ie. if you wanted to access the 0th list in the outermost dimension you would call `x[0]`

```
>>> x[0]
[1, 2]
```

This could also be called accessing the 0th *row*. I think this is by convention, nothing more. To access the *inner* dimension we'd have to get to it first, by chosing the outer dimension. So if we want the 1st element in the *inner* dimension of the 0th element in the *outer* dimension, we would call `x[0][1]`:

```
>>> x[0][1]
2
```

**Time or space:**

The outermost dimension is the batch, and the innermost is the feature. The *middle* indices are therefore the aspects of the feature that we're presenting to the model. These could be `x` and `y` coordinates, or perhaps `time` vs `amplitude` of a soundwave.